# How to run svnserve protocol to server multiple paths

Tags: svn, svnserve, svn-server

I am setting up a svn server where I have more than one SVN repository paths like /var/data/svnrepos1/forclient1 and /var/data/svnrepos2/forclient2. The SVN is installed in a custom path /usr/install/svn1.8/bin/{svnadmin,svnserve,svn,etc}.

---

I am try running the svnserve program using commandline like below. The command issued at command prompt is `/usr/install/svn1.8/bin/svnserve -d -r /var/data/svnrepos/forclient1 -r /var/data/svnrepos2/forclient2` But SVN program is serving for just second path `/var/data/svnrepos2/forclient2` only. The repos could not be accessible  under `/var/data/svnrepos1/forclient1`. I have checked by running the daemon like { -r path2 -r path1}. In this case working for path1.` Any idea how multiple paths can be set by svn program.

Comment: The post looks good now. Thanks Badger.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- Move repositories to common parent (`/var/data/svnrepos` f.e) and have repos *forclient1* and *forclient2* served by single instance (just configure ACLs for different repos properly)
- Run two instances of svnserve on **different ports** with  **single unique root** in each

Comment: I agree that moving to common parent would serve this purpose. What I believe is SVN will read immediate directory/repositories under path marked in flag "-r". However, I can not move the repos to common parent. We do not want to move to one parent since two are completely different type of repo code except these repositories are created with SVN 1.8 version. There should be trick but I do not know that.

Comment: @arunp - no, it's not as Apache's `SVNParentPath` style. You can have root at *any level* above repo - it will change only full URL of repository. And you **can** have -r /var/data/

Comment: Yeah Badger ~ the repo is working with full URL of repository. Is that possible to run the svnserve with multiple paths using "-r" options. So that parent directory of repo path is not required in the URL.  [svn://servername/svnrepos/repository ] I feel parent directory where the repository is residing should be hidden from users.

Comment: @arunp - no, you can not have more than one `-r` instance per daemon. I.e. you have to use only p.2